# React yup - Not allow Exclamation mark in the email field

Tags: reactjs, yup, email-validation

I have a problem with the email field, I want to block the user if his inputs include **Exclamation mark** in the email field. For example, if the user input consists of the **Exclamation mark**, the email field will show `Email address cannot use exclamation mark`

Below is my current code for email yup validation, currently just can to normally validate email format, but I am not sure how to block the exclamation mark in the below coding:

```html
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
email: Yup.string()
      .email(
        intl.formatMessage({
          id: "10003",
        })
      )
      .min(
        3,
        intl.formatMessage({
          id: "AUTH.VALIDATION.MIN_LENGTH_FIELD",
        }) + " 3"
      )
      .max(
        50,
        intl.formatMessage({
          id: "AUTH.VALIDATION.MAX_LENGTH_FIELD",
        }) + " 50"
      )
      .required(
        intl.formatMessage({
          id: "AUTH.VALIDATION.REQUIRED_FIELD",
        })
      ),
});
```

Below is what I've tried, I tried to add the matches in the yup object, but it can not work:

```html
.matches(
        /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|([0-9]{10})+$/,
        intl.formatMessage({
          id: "AUTH.NOT_ALLOW_EXCLAMATION_MARK",
        })
      )
```

**Sample result:**

[image: 12]

**Another question**: May I know still have which symbols not allowed user input in the email field except exclamation mark?

I hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/^[^not-allowed-characters-here]+$/` regex in `yup` to validating invalid characters. Add below code to your schema chain.

```
.matches(/^[^!]+$/, intl.formatMessage({
      id: "AUTH.NOT_ALLOW_EXCLAMATION_MARK",
    }))
```

If you want to prevent `+` in future for example, just include it there:

```
.matches(/^[^!+]+$/, intl.formatMessage({
          id: "AUTH.NOT_ALLOW_EXCLAMATION_MARK",
        }))
```